# PHP buttons in 'for' and onclick with parameter

Tags: php, loops, button, parameters, onclick

My problem is that I want to make one button for each $i incrementation in my loop, and on the click of one button, I must call an include of another PHP file, but passing a parameter (a link) to the included PHP.
So here is what I have tried:

```
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
    $link="https://www.google.fr/search?q=$i"; //for example
    echo '
    <form method="post">
        <button name="button$link">Hello</button>
    </form>';

    // generate random string to have random variable name (unique)
    $seed = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.'0123456789');
    shuffle($seed); 
    $rand = '';
    foreach (array_rand($seed, 5) as $k){
        $rand .= $seed[$k];
    } 

    $$rand=$link; //puts the parameter (link) in the dynamic variable

    if(isset($_POST["button$$rand"])){
        include("other.php"); // $$rand is used in that function
    }
}
```

So I tried with dynamic variables, but as the part that 'checks if a button is clicked' does its job out of the loop, I cannot get the right button name.

Comment: You want to create dynamic variables by means of a randomized string? Isn't that pretty dangerous? What if, by accident, some other variable is overwritten? Sorry, but you really should change that approach. At least put the dynamic variables inside some specific container (an array) to be more robust.

Comment: Apart from that, relying on post values to include additional code is also extremely risky. Everyone can fake such post data easily, so everyone can include arbitrary scripts into your code and trick you into running those scripts! Maybe even remote scripts!

Comment: And last: I do not get the idea behind that final `include` statement: `include` expects exactly one single parameter, the file name. Yet you hand over _two_ arguments separated by a white space. _Why?_ What is that meant to do?

Comment: A final note about your specific issue: I have the impression you somehow mix separate requests here. How should a post request to this script contain exactly the randomized string you just create inside this script?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["button$$rand"])){
        include("other.php $$rand");
    }` will not work

Comment: Yes you are right about the include, in fact I did not wright the argument next to the filename, I just used it in the other PHP. But we could not see the argument if I did not write the code like this. My bad. Anyway, I already made this code work with HiddenDiv and javascript but I need that the other PHP file executes itself only when the button is clicked and not execute itself and be hidden until click.

Comment: I used dynamic variables because I did not find another idea. Anyway it does not work so if you have an idea..

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution !
I used ajax.
So on every button there is a call to an ajax function, and you can pass a parameter to the ajax function (a link in my case)

It should be something like this:

```
<button onclick="function('parameter')">
```